# Creating failed message on WCF-CustomIsolated Receive Location

Tags: wcf, biztalk, wcf-binding, biztalk-2013

I have a receive port with a WCF-CustomIsolated receive location.

On receive port I checked "Enable routing for failed messages".

In pipeline settings I have set ValidateDocument to true.

When a client sends me an incorrect schema, it receives a validation error (that happened in pipeline) and it's OK.

But it's not routed as a fault message to message box.

Could you help me why does it happen?

Why "routing for failed messages" does not work in this case? And in what cases it should work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

On the Receive Location, go the Transport Properties, Messages, Error Handling, and check Suspend request message on failure.
Even though it says "Suspend" checking this in combination with the Routing for Failed Message on the Receive Port will actually create a FailedMessage that you are after.  (If Routing for Failed Message isn't enabled it will suspend).

This applies to all the WCF adapters, not just the CustomIsolated one.

Comment: The problem is that if I check "Suspend request message on failure" then the client receives no error. But I want the client to receive the SOAP Fault too.

Comment: Strange, I don't get that behaviour in BizTalk 2010.  Is it just two way port (request/response) or just a one way port?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the error message.  You could use a send port or orchestration with a filter set to the receive port, message type and/or message error.

Comment: It isn't creating any message for anything to subscribe too, see my answer as to how to get a WCF receive location to actually get it to create a failed message.

Comment: Ah, misread the question. I'll leave it up there as it's the next step.